# uniary operator expected on first run of bash script - how do I work around this?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

#script complains if our lastdownfile dosen't exist.
latestripcord=`elinks -dump https://cancel.fm/ripcord/ -no-numbering| grep Ripcord_Win  | cut -c 5-`
#standard elinks dump scripty goodness. the cut -c 5- is to strip the leading zero
lastdownloadripcord=`cat lastdownload`
#we have stored the last download in a text file.
version=`echo $lastdownloadripcord | cut -d _ -f3| cut -d . -f 1-3`
#maybe we can do more with the version?
if [ $latestripcord == $lastdownloadripcord ];then
    echo "latest version $version installed"
#to do - strip out and store the latest version number somewhere for use in the script.
else
    echo $latestripcord|tee lastdownload| curl -sS $latestripcord > ripcord.zip
    unzip ripcord.zip -d ./ripcord
#if we  have a new version, update last downloaded version and download  latest. Unzip to its own dir
fi
```

Essentially - I'm dumping out a download link for an application that's shipped as a zip file, storing the link to compare later so I know a new version is out, and if so, downloading the latest version.

I've tested this with a "fake" new version, by editing out the last download file. However on first run, there's no lastdownload file which results in 2 error messages.

```
cat: lastdownload: No such file or directory
./autoripcord.sh: line 9: [: https://cancel.fm/dl/Ripcord_Win_0.4.24.zip: unary operator expecte
```

The former is because there's no lastdownload file, the latter because there's nothing for the statement on line 9 to compare to. I'm fine on subsequent runs since the file is generated and there's a value to compare.

What would be the 'right' way to handle this? In theory, I could create a dummy file (but that solves the first, not the second error). In theory I can add another loop to check for the existence of the temporary storage file but that feels like overkill.

Comment: `[ foo = $bar ]` Is the simple example that can reproduce your error. Always quote your variables, and prefer to use the `[[` rather than `[`, just my two cents.

Comment: Oh. I'm aware it's empty. And I totally echoed the variables as I built this. I'm wondering if there's a simple workaround for that first run..Dervis answer seems to work but I am curious to the why as much as the what

Comment: if your $latestripcord  or $lastdownloadripcord  contains spaces or other special characters, you will get this error, use doublequotas "$lastdownloadripcord". Other way in bash you can use [[ ]] operator instead of [ ] which solves these issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
if [ $latestripcord == $lastdownloadripcord ];then
```

With

```
if [[ $latestripcord == $lastdownloadripcord ]];then
```

Comment: That does seem to work. How's the single and double square bracket different?